# Do keyboard docks specified for the iPad2 work with the iPad?

Tags: ipad, keyboard

I was looking on the Apple store for a keyboard for my iPad (specifically [this product](http://store.apple.com/uk/product/MC533B/A?fnode=MTc0MjU4OTY#overview)) and it doesn't say if it is compatible only with the iPad2 or if it also works with the original iPad.

Would it generally be the case that docked hardware like this would work with both iPads, or has something changed in the iPad2 that might break compatibility with the original iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it says it is compatible with iPad, it is compatible with the iPad 1, iPad 2, theoretically the iPhone 4/S. I have it.

Comment: And you use it with which iDevice specifically?